# How do I implement tracking a text to speech so it shows the line it's reading from

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech

I'm building a book app for kids and I just added the text to speech feature.
I want to write a code that shows ( more like underline or change the color) the word the TTS is saying. Like those kiddies sing along.
Would appreciate any help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is very broad, and this site focuses on **specific** issues. Please consider reading the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the site to help improve your post. It is difficult for us to help, as you have not provided any example code, and described *specifically* where you have gotten stuck. Hope this helps!

Comment: Wasn't implying that it was @Andreas. I'm not looking for someone to write a code for me. Just a point in the right direction would do, even if it is "It is just not possible". Thank you

Comment: In here, you're expected to do your research and attempts beforehand and include it along with the specific issue in the question. As of now, your question is simply too broad

Comment: Full disclosure I work for CereProc, but our TTS produces a transcript alongside the audio that can be used for word highlighting.

Comment: As far as TTS on Android is concerned, the most fine-grained unit is the "utterance" -- which is an arbitrary string of characters you send to the TTS which it processes and "speaks."  There is no concept of "words" or "sentences." Unless you want to write your own TTS engine, your best hope is to highlight utterance-by-utterance -- presumably sentences, because word-by-word would sound stilted.  In order to to make realtime changes to your UI you need to use an UtteranceProgressListener.